# Hibernate for simple query

Tags: java, hibernate

I am a newbie in hibernate and started working on it . I am trying to use hibernate for one of my project which contains a simple Login page . 
Someone (senior) told me why to use hibernate for such a simple query, it will have a performance issue and I should use simple JDBC for that page.

Can anyone advice me for what type of queries I can use in hibernate ?

Thanks

Comment: You could read this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607819/weaknesses-of-hibernate?rq=1

Comment: I don't what was wrong in the question that someone just down voted it . Maybe gentleman who downvoted it can explain ?

Comment: @JoseLuis Thanks for the reply , I have already read that answer .. I was confused , that it is really good idea to use JDBC for some pages in my application .

Answer (score 0):

The question of performance is everywhere and not unique to hibernate so it all depends on how you structure your Project because even in JDBC for example there is a strong argument of using `PreparedStatement` in place of `Statement`. In Hibernate you can use `HSQL` or opt for the more cool `Criteria` API. I actually prefer the `Criteria` API because I do not have to write any query, I leave that to the Hibernate engine.

So assuming you have a table called `Users` in your database and it contains the username and password for login in users, a simple `boolean` method like this will serve you very well and as you can notice, you will not need to write any query. This actually makes your application more independent in regards to databases because it works with most databases with minimal changes.

```
public static boolean userExists(String userName, String userPassword) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        long count = 0;
        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Users.class);//Users.class is the mapping class for your database Objects.
            cr.add(Restrictions.eq("userName", userName));
            cr.add(Restrictions.eq("userPassword", userPassword));
            count = (Long) cr.setProjection(Projections.rowCount()).uniqueResult();
            tx.commit();
        } catch (Exception asd) {
            System.out.println(asd.getMessage());
            if (tx != null) {
                tx.rollback();
            }
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return count > 0;
    }
```

So when you pass username and password parameters if a user and password matches, the `boolean` will return `true` otherwise it will return `false`. 
In the background the engine will generate this query:

```
select count(*) from Users where user_name = ? and user_password = ?
```

There is a nice tutorial [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_criteria_queries.htm) where you can refer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have already used Criteria API and because of that, someone told me it is an overkill to use it just for the login page .